# Row bind dataframes named as strings in a vector

Tags: r

I am struggling on how to row bind dataframes whose names are inside a vector as strings:

I have tried:

```
dflist<-c("df1", "df2", "df3")
dfnames<-c(sapply(dflist, function(x) eval(parse(text = "x"))))

dfFinal<-rbind(dfnames)
```

But, this is not working: `dfnames` still contains strings instead of variable names.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the object names as strings in a `list` and then `rbind` the `list` elements (assuming that these objects have the same column names - if it is data.frame)

```
do.call(rbind, unname(mget(dflist)))
```

---

In the OP's post, the `x` is quoted "x", instead it should be

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dflist, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
```

NOTE: It may be better to use `mget`

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3)
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = 7:9)
dflist<-c("df1", "df2", "df3")
```